# Why the property is not setting in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

I have a LWC component. The JS file is like below

```
export default class Atsite_activity extends LightningElement {
    
    @api 
    activitydata=[];

    @api filterActivityData = [];

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.activitydata = getSessionStorage('formattedActivityData');
        this.filterActivityData = this.activitydata;
   }
}

export function getSessionStorage(key) {
    return JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key));
}
```

I have a thought that, the 2 lines inside constructor executes sequentially as there is no asynchronous operation here. `this.activitydata = getSessionStorage('formattedActivityData');` will return data and in the next line `this.filterActivityData = this.activitydata;` will be assigned with the returned data by the function.

But, `this.activitydata` is blank while executing `this.filterActivityData = this.activitydata;`.

My question is, why it is behaving like this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should be calling it on `connectedCallback` instead of during the `constructor`

Answer (score 2):

`@api` attributes are not initialized while `constructor()` is being called.

You can try shifting the logic to `connectedCallback()`

**OR**

You can remove `@api` if you dont need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you open your component with debug mode enabled, most likely you'll see the following error:

```
Error: [LWC error]: Can’t read the value of property `activitydata` from the constructor because the owner component hasn’t set the value yet. Instead, use the constructor to set a default value for the property.
```

You cannot read `@api` properties in the constructor. Removing the `@api` decorator should fix the problem. Or if you want to keep the possibility to set `activitydata` from parent components, you'll need to move the logic that reads value from `activitydata` to `connectedCallback()`.